# How to expand A UIView to cover multiple cells

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, xib

I have a calendar and inside every cell I have a table view. Inside the table view cell I have a UIView. All of these are done using xib.
Everything is working fine.
What I want is to expand that UIView to cover multiple cells of the calendar.(Collection View)

[image: I want that red view to cover date 03 and 04.]

I want that red view to cover date 03 and 04.

Comment: I would probably reload the cells you wanna change and load custom cell for that specific use case.

Comment: That is not the problem. The view is ok there, i just need to make it bigger to cover more calendar cells. And I can’t seem to make the width bigger than the table view.

Comment: Even if you disabled clipping (`clipsToBounds`) on the parent views and allowed your cell's view to span different "columns", you would face another problem when you'd like to fill ranges that span different "rows" (3 to 6 for example). The suggestion above seems ok (essentially you could give the _impression_ that the shash is extending by replicating it across) but you then should have to deal with borders. Maybe overlaid views with a custom layout would be a better approach.